Clicking on a button does not always bring the same result
I'm trying to take all the colors of a product, but first I have to click on a button to show all the available ones. When I do it, sometimes it is successful, other times it just brings me the default color as if I had not clicked on the drop-down button. I have tried to defend waiting times without success. I'm trying to understand why this behavior is happening. I've tried to wait for a div (id="tippy-5") which is the drop-down, but it makes an error since the click is never sent correctly.
Update: If I put a breakpoint on the page.click, and then I continue, it always throws the desired behavior. If I put the breakpoint after, it's the opposite.
public class StockFetcher {

    public static List<String> getStockFromWebPage() {
        List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<>();
        String productUrl = "https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.pe/MPE-653839472-tapones-loop-quiet";
        try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(true));
            Page page = browser.newPage();
            page.navigate(productUrl);
            page.waitForSelector(".andes-dropdown__trigger", new Page.WaitForSelectorOptions().setTimeout(5000));
            page.click(".andes-dropdown__trigger");
            // page.waitForSelector("#tippy-5", new
            // Page.WaitForSelectorOptions().setTimeout(5000));
            List<ElementHandle> elements = page.querySelectorAll(".ui-pdp-dropdown-selector__item--label-small");
            for (ElementHandle element : elements) {
                String textContent = element.textContent();
                stockList.add(textContent);
            }
            page.close();
        }
        return stockList;
    }
}

